# Add own javascript to validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I don't know very much about c#.  I am updating a page built by someone else and I want to add a script to a button web control.  The form is using c#'s validation and when I look at the returned markup from opening the page, there already is an onclick event handler for the postback submission and validation.  So how do I add my own as well?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the button's `OnClientClick` property to place custom clientside script. Documentation on it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Here is the official ASP.NET QuickStart Tutorial for [ASP.NET Validation Controls](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/validation/default.aspx). By the way if you're looking for your custom validation, check [CustomValidator Control](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020145934/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/073102-1.aspx), specifically it's ClientValidationFunction property.